# Can the passage of time be called an Effect?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngxs

I know that we can subscribe to actions and depending on what action is dispatched we can dispatch new actions - it can be safely called the `Effect`, but ...

What if I want to dispatch some actions after the date I keep in state? I care about the good organization of the code in the project, so it is important for me to properly name such a function.

**Can the function subcribe for the passage of time and perform actions if `time === 0` can be called an `Effect`?**

```
mySelector
      .getTime(this.store)
      .pipe(skipWhile(time => time > 0))
      .subscribe(data => {
        // this.store.dispatch([...]);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you store in the effects and it can help to solve your issue.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthActivationSelfEffects {
    public readonly scheduler$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            switchMap(() => this.store.select(getTime)),
            skipWhile(time => time > 0),
            switchMap(() => [
                action1,
                action2,
                action3,
            ]),
        ),
    );

    constructor(protected readonly store: Store) {}
}
```

The right way would be to have a start action and an end action which are triggered somewhere from controllers.
Because effects are for side effects, not for scheduling.

it would look like:

```js
.pipe(
  ofType(startAction),
  delay(5000), // time to wait
  takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(endAction))), // cancel
  switchMap(() => [action1, action2, action3]), // actions to dispatch if it wasn't canceled.
);
```